# Can you use igraph to look at layers and sum node attributes?

Tags: r, igraph

I'm trying to design a solution for the employee cost across different subsets of an organisation which follows a tree structure. I'm using igraph in R have have put together some sample code and examples of questions I'm trying to answer. I'd really appreciate some help. Thanks

```
library(igraph)

# sample graph
g <- graph.tree(6, children = 2) %>% 
  set_vertex_attr("EmployeeID",value = LETTERS[1:6]) %>% 
  set_vertex_attr("Salary",value = 100 - 1:6*10) %>% 
  set_vertex_attr("label",value = paste("\n\n\nEmployee:",V(.)$EmployeeID,"\nSalary:",V(.)$Salary)) 

plot(g, layout=layout.reingold.tilford)
```

1.What is the cost of the whole organisation under Employee A? I.e. iterate through all descendants to add up the salary attribute:

```
90+80+60+50+70+40
```

2.What is the cost of layer 3?

```
60+50+40
```

3.Show the number of direct reports for each manager:

```
A:2
B:2
C:1
```

4.How many employees only have 1 direct report?

```
1 Employee
C
```

Comment: That is a lot questions.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your feedback. This is my first post here. Basically I'm trying to figure out how to extract different sets of nodes and their properties. Such as descendant properties or layers of nodes. Thought it would be helpful to put in a few examples. Any help, even partial answers would be very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too many questions for one "question" at Stack Overfow. Please read
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
You will need to try some things on your own and when you get stuck, can ask for specific help.

However,  let me get you started. To work with graphs like this,  you will need to be able to select the nodes that you want.

## 1.What is the cost of the whole organisation under Employee A?

You can identify the nodes that you want using `subcomponent`.

```
BelowA = subcomponent(g, which(V(g)$EmployeeID == "A") , mode = "out")
BelowA
+ 6/6 vertices:
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
sum(V(g)$Salary[BelowA])
[1] 390
```

## 2.What is the cost of layer 3?

You need to define the layers. That is the distance from node A plus one. Then select those that are in layer 3.

```
Depth = 1 + distances(g, v = which(V(g)$EmployeeID == "A"))
Depth
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    2    2    3    3    3
sum(V(g)$Salary[Depth == 3])
[1] 150
```

Please try to do the rest yourself. If you get stuck,  show us the code that you tried and why it isn't working.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and feedback. I'll give this a go and try out the rest of the questions myself. This has been incredibly helpful.

Comment: Thank you @G5W for your help with my question. Your answer really helped me to better understand how to work with iGraph. Here are my solutions for the remaining 2 questions

# 3.Show the number of direct reports for each manager

`V(g)$DirectReports <- rowSums(distances(g, v = V(g),mode = "out") == 1)
V(g)$DirectReports`

# 4.How many employees only have 1 direct report? Eg only 1 employee C manages a single employee

`V(g)$DirectReports == 1`

Comment: Good job.  Thanks for sharing your answers to the other questions.